# is there an numpy function that will return an array with different combinations of the original?

Tags: numpy

For example if my array was

```
(2,2)
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

I would want it to return:

```
(4,2,2)
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],
       [[1, 1],
        [0, 1]],
       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],
       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

Comment: Could you either try to state more clearly what you mean by combinations or at least give a few more examples? It is not at all obvious how your input leads to your output.

Comment: For example, given your input we could get your output as `(np.kron(inp, inp)^inp.ravel()).reshape(-1, *inp.shape)` but I doubt that is the rule you have in mind.

Comment: essentially I want to test the significance of individual values for me data. So I want to take the original (for example a (2,2) matrix) and return an array with one value at a time manipulated (in the (2,2) example it would return a (4,2,2). As you can see, in the returned array, there are four identical arrays to original, with one value changed in each.

Comment: Your data are binary?

Comment: Yes, it is binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip binary number at a time using:

```
(np.identity(inp.size, int)^inp.ravel()).reshape(-1, *inp.shape)
```

or more verbose but also more economical:

```
>>> out = np.empty(2*(inp.size,), inp.dtype)
>>> out[...] = inp.ravel()
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', out)[...]^=1
>>> out = out.reshape(-1, *inp.shape)
```